# Using implicit conversion instead Adapter pattern

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have a project written in MVC style. Views look like this:

```
trait BaseView {
  def asComponent(): Component // each view can be displayed on screen
}


class ConcreteView extends Panel with BaseView  {

  def asComponent(): Component = this //ConcreteView is itself Component because it extends Panel 
}
```

It is possible to change this code to use implicit conversion from `ConcreteView` to `Component`? So I can use `ConcreteView` as `Component` (due implicit conversion) without calling  `ConcreteView#asComponent` method?

Comment: Why would you even need such a method? `val c: Component = someConcreteView` should already work.

Comment: To understand better when you should and when shouldn't use implicit conversions for Adapter patter I recommend you to read my blog post - http://maxondev.com/adapter-design-pattern-scala-implicits/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just define an implicit conversion from BaseView to Component that calls the asComponent method.

```
object BaseView {
  implicit def viewIsComponent(x:BaseView) : Component = x.asComponent
}
```

But that does not mean that it is a good idea. An implicit conversion in scala is a very powerful feature. If a BaseView (and by inheritance each XXXView) *is a* Component, that means that you will get all methods of Component when you want to call a method of val myView:SomeView. That totally clutters the namespace and also can be dangerous because you are not sure if you call a method of your View or of the Component it is implicitly mapped to.

In the scala library there has been a move away from implicit conversions to more explicit and slightly more verbose way. Take for example [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions%24): they provide implicit conversions from scala collections to java collections and back. This sounds like a good idea, but it has caused a lot of trouble in practice:

- conversions happening when you don't expect them to
- the namespace of the scala collections cluttered with a lot of additional methods from the java equivalent
- difficult to find issues when new methods are added to the target of the implicit conversion that collide with methods in the source of the conversion

The currently recommended way to deal with java/scala collection interop is to use the more explicit [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters%24), which add a single method asScala to java collections and asJava to scala collections.

So just leave the method as is. Maybe change the name to just .component, since you don't really *convert* the view to the component, but only allow somebody to *access* the component that each view must have.